# req.body.param keep getting value of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

Keep getting undefined value inside my put request but in my post request it returns the correct value. Any ideas why?

`req.body.name` returns the correct value here.

`api.js`

```
router.post('/testdb/', function(req, res, next){
Process.create(req.body).then(function(proc){
    res.send(proc);
    teller++;
  fs.open('schedule.txt', 'a', (err, fd) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.appendFile(fd, req.body.name +"\r\n", 'utf8', (err) => {
      fs.close(fd, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });
}).catch(next);
});
```

`req.body.name` returns the undefined value here

```
router.put('/testdb/', bodyParser.json(), function (req, res) {
  for (let k = 1; k < teller; k++) {
    Process.findOne({ at: k }, req.body).then(function () {
      res.send()
      fs.open('schedule.txt', 'a', (err, fd) => {
        if (err) throw err
        fs.appendFile(fd, req.body.name + '\r\n', 'utf8', err => {
          fs.close(fd, err => {
            if (err) throw err
          })
          if (err) throw err
        })
      })
    })
  }
  for (let arrivet = 1; arrivet <= teller; arrivet++) {
    Process.findOneAndUpdate({ at: arrivet }, req.body, { new: true }, function (error, docc) {})
  }
})
```

Comment: i do use app.use(bodyParser());  app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParserurlencoded({extended:true}));

Comment: Have you tried removing the `bodyParser.json()` from your `router.put`?

Comment: I only used it to try and get a value but will try and post now

Comment: Still undefined

Comment: Can it help you https://github.com/expressjs/method-override/issues/13